# Overwrite nested config options on command line

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to overwrite nested config options with **Snakemake's** --config command line option? For example: an option accessed internally with `config['step_a']['opt_b']`. Is there some syntax to specify this when starting the Snakemake workflow?

Answer (score 1):

This works but you would need to supply other elements of the step_a dict:

```
--config "step_a={'opt_b':'c'}"
```

I think the proper way is to have a different config file using `--configfile`.
If there is some config that is relatively static and some that is changeable, use two config files. You can supply multiple config files using `--configfile`.